# React - Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dom, expo

I am new to React, doing a small project with Expo for my school assignment. The final product has to be a mobile app, but I've encountered an error I can't get trough. The app is running perfectly fine on web browser, API calls work, switching windows work. The thing is, when I run the project on a mobile device, I got the error in the picture. I went through first 2 google pages and plenty of questions here tried "ReactDOM.render", tried to nest App into BrowserRouter with Routes in different place, basically, everything I could find, (not saying I tried everything correctly). Unfortunately, I am still getting the error.

Can anyone you Help me? Maybe explain what am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks, Lukas.

The code for my App.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import AddNews from './AddNews';
import AllNews from './AllNews';
import NewsId from './NewsId';

export default class App extends React.Component{

  render(){

    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={AllNews}/> 
            <Route exact path='/addnews' component={AddNews}/> 
            <Route exact path='/newsid/:id' component={NewsId}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Picture:[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNcyz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changing BrowserRouter to MemoryRoute.